# Query with CONCAT inside JOIN is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, concatenation

I need to get different values from 3 different tables (table1, table2, table3) where the common value is a reference number. This number appears on all 3 tables, except on table3 where the number is divided on three different columns. I tried to make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` concatenating these three columns to make the whole reference number, but the query becomes significantly slower. This is the part of the query where the issue is found:

```
SELECT t1.type AS type, t2.client AS client, t3.somenumber AS somenumber, t4.anothernumber AS anothernumber

FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.somevalue = t2.somevalue
JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.reference_number = t1.reference_number --Some validation I need to make on another table

--Here's the problem. table3's values 1 through 3 make the reference number found in the other tables.
--The CONCAT makes the query significantly slow.
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON CONCAT(t3.value1, t3.value2, t3.value3) = t1.reference_number

WHERE t1.date BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-05-01'
AND t1.client IN ('client1', 'client2', 'client3', 'client4', 'client5') 

GROUP BY t1.reference_number --Group by the reference number
```

I tried making a view to create a column where the reference number is 'stored', but it still takes a lot to run the query. Is there a way to optimize this?

Running on 10.3.32-MariaDB

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  you likely want an index on a generated column in table3

Comment: @ysth It shows `10.3.32-MariaDB` If it could help make the query faster, I would totally try that

Comment: I would ignore performance for the moment. There is a potential logic/design mistake.  Show the result of the following: `SELECT MIN(value1), MAX(value1), MIN(value2), MAX(value2), MIN(value3), MAX(value3) FROM table3;`  If those values don't follow a strict pattern, your CONCAT(val1, val2, val3) will not be unique enough `CONCAT(1, 23, 4) = CONCAT(12, 3, 4)`.

Comment: *`ON CONCAT(t3.value1, t3.value2, t3.value3) = t1.reference_number`* Function in joining condition causes full table scan unconditionally. The only way to improve seems to be in crearting generated column with this expression, indexing it, and using it instead of the expression in the query.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Indeed, those values don't follow a pattern. I got blanks for `MIN(value1)` and `MIN(value2)`, a middle dash for `MIN(value3)`, and some numbers for `MAX(value1)`,  `MAX(value2)` and  `MAX(value3)`.

Comment: @Akina Yeah, I read about that. I would prefer to not alter the table, but it seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY does not need `CONCAT`:

```
GROUP BY t3.value1, t3.value2, t3.value3
```

I don't understand why you tacked on `t1.reference_number`; it is either similar info or `NULL`.  The `NULL` case might lead to extra groups, by it seems like a waste.  (Add it on if necessary.)

Indexes:

```
t1:  INDEX(date)
t1:  INDEX(client, date)
t2:  INDEX(somevalue,  client)
t3:  INDEX(value1, value2, value3)
t4:  INDEX(reference_number)
```

Was `t3.value` a typo for `t3.value3`?

Consider getting rid of `t4`; you are not using any values from it.  The only thing it is doing is to verify that `table4` has a matching row.

What version of MySQL are you using?

It may be useful to have `VIRTUAL` or `PERSISTENT` (generated) column that is `CONCAT (value1, value2, value3)` and index it.

(And I agree with the Commenters that the "reference number" is ambiguous.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I actually just need to `GROUP BY t1.reference_number`.  I need to make joins using `t1.reference_number` because it is the common value between these tables. `t3.value` was just some random value I need (there are more, but I omitted them because they didn't seem necessary, they are not making the query slow). I need some values from `t4`. I just created a `VIRTUAL` column and, sadly, it is still slow.

Comment: @ArminAH - Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with the virtual column and its new indexes.  Plus `EXPLAIN`.  There may be something subtle that I failed to mention.